# Get first previous non matched element from array

Tags: python, list

I would like to fetch the first non matched element while iterating backwards.

Here is my input array:

```
data = ['2017','No 1','No 2','2018','No 3','No 4','No 5']
```

And, the expected result is,

```
['2017', '2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018']
```

Strings `"No 1"` and `"No 2"` have to be mapped to string `"2017"`.

Basically I would like to return the string that does not match `"No"` by iterating previous.

The below snippet does what I'm expecting, but I would like to know is there a better way to do this

```
def get_name(i, d):
  if d.find('No') >= 0:
    return get_name(i - 1, data[i - 1])
  else:
    return d

[get_name(i,d) for i,d in enumerate(data)]
```

Comment: What happens if the first element of the list is `"No 1"`?

Comment: Yes its a list of strings. They need not always be of the format Unnamed: XYZ or Year ZYX.. But I'll have a condition to choose elements. .For instance "Unnamed" or I have edited question with string "No"..

Comment: Yes.. That's a nice case! I don't have a data with such case! In that case I might want to return a default value may be "default". Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember the last "good" item and yield either that one, or the actual item.

```
def func(lst, default=None):
    last = default
    for e in lst:
        last = e if not e.startswith("No") else last
        yield last

>>> data = ['2017','No 1','No 2','2018','No 3','No 4','No 5']
>>> list(func(data))
['2017', '2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018']
```

Comment: This is great with `yield`.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm striggling to figure out what exactly are you trying to achieve. If you want just to keep replacing elements in a list with the last non-match you can do it with far less complexity and without recursion as:

```
def get_name(data, match):
    result = []  # store for our result
    last_element = None  # store the last non-matching element
    for element in data:  # go through each element
        if match in element:  # if match...
            result.append(last_element)  # add the last non-matching element
        else:
            last_element = element  # set the last non-matching element to the current
            result.append(element)  # add it to the result
    return result  # return the result

data = ['2017','No 1','No 2','2018','No 3','No 4','No 5']
print(get_name(data, "No"))  # ['2017', '2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018']
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be unnecessary, but you can also try a stack based approach:

```
def get_name(lst, match):
    result = []
    stack = []

    for elem in lst:
        if elem.startswith(match):
            if stack:
                top = stack[-1]
                result.append(top)
            else:
                result.append(None)
        else:
            stack.append(elem)
            result.append(elem)

    return result

print(get_name(['2017','No 1','No 2','2018','No 3','No 4','No 5'], "No"))
# ['2017', '2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018']

print(get_name(['No1','No 2','No 3','2018','No 4','No 5','No 6'], "No"))
# [None, None, None, '2018', '2018', '2018', '2018']

print(get_name(['No1','No 2','No 3','2017','No 4','2018','No 6'], "No"))
# [None, None, None, '2017', '2017', '2018', '2018']
```

The default value here is `None`, if their are no recent years to use.